# Toggling jQuery animation not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Trying to do a simple animation on click. I have a panel thats hidden off to the right side (absolute positioned) when the user clicks the tab i want the panel to slide out. I can get the initial slide out to work but cant get the toggle to function properly

```
 $('#sideTab').click(function() {
           $('#sideCol').animate({'right':'0%'}) 
        }, function ()
            $('#sideCol').animate({'right':'-50%'})                    
        });


 $('#sideTab').toggle(function() {
           $('#sideCol').animate({'right':'0%'}) 
        }, function ()
            $('#sideCol').animate({'right':'-50%'})                    
        });
```

neither of these are working

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/BQE32/1/

when the green square is clicked the blue square should move left, and when its clicked again it should move back to original positioning

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`click` doesn't accept two callback functions, you can read the `right` property and set the proper value:

```
$('#sideTab').click(function () {
    var $e = $('#sideCol');
    $e.animate({
       'right': $e.css('right') === '0px' ? '-50%' : '0px'
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Jrs36/

You can also use CSS `transition` property and jQuery `.toggleClass()` method:

CSS:

```
#sideCol {
   -webkit-transition: right 400ms;
   -moz-transition: right 400ms;
   -o-transition: right 400ms;
   transition: right 400ms; 
} 

#sideCol.right50 {
    right: 50%;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
$('#sideTab').click(function () {
    $('#sideCol').toggleClass('right50');
});
```

Comment: never seen this written before, is that 'right' line essientially saying if 0 do 50%, else do 0px?

Comment: @user934902 Yes, it does so.

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#sideTab').on('click', function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass('toggled') === true) {
        $(this).animate({'right': '-50%'}).removeClass('toggled');
    } else {
        $(this).animate({'right': '0'}).addClass('toggled');
    }
});
```

This will check if the sidebar is already 'toggled', and if it is will remove the class and animate it back out of the frame (and vice versa).

Answer (score 1):

You can use [toggle()](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) here:

```
$('#sideTab').toggle(function() {
  $('#sideCol').animate({'right':'0%'}) 
}, function() {
  $('#sideCol').animate({'right':'-50%'}) 
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/BQE32/4/)

Comment: this version of toggle is no more supported without the migration plugin

Comment: @ArunPJohny we don't know what version OP's using, even he's using lastest version, that's still a valid option though